Can we use mocking frameworks for load testing or should we create interfaces to inject dummy data into a class?
I have a service 'S' which has the logic to generate a report and download it. It is written in spring-boot and java. This is consumed by another system 'B' that has the data in its database 'C' that needs to be put into the report.
A button is clicked and the data is queried by 'B' from 'C' and stored in a java pojo class which gets written to a excel file and is stored in cloud. This happens in 'B'
We want to do load testing for 'S' using some dummy data. Can we somehow inject our sample resultset into 'B' when it fires query to its database without making any code changes in 'B'? This sample result-set will then be used to generate the report. (B's jars are attached to 'S')
I was wondering if we can use any testing framework like Mockito, JOOQ, testContainers, since this is not a unit testing scenario or integration testing, to control what goes into the resultset. This is only for load testing purpose and relevant measures will be taken for this to not go to Production.
Please let me know your views.
We can use mockito with scope compile to do the mocking but I am not sure if this or any testing framework is recommended for this case.

I cannot comment on Mockito as I don't know that API. Regarding the other libraries that you asked for:
jOOQ
The jOOQ library includes:

a programmatic MockingConnection, where you can mock the JDBC API programmatically
a file based mock database, where you can match SQL strings to text based results

Both of these approaches can help with producing dummy result sets for your purpose.
You don't need to use jOOQ in your application to get this to work, as both approaches act as JDBC API implementations.
Testcontainers:
This will offer a more robust approach to testing than mocking, as you will be able to integration test your code. It will be closer to productive performance characteristics as you can use a real database product inside of a docker container, with all the transactional behaviour etc. It's generally good to use an integration testing approach with databases, although, obviously tests will be quite slower than if using mocks.

Hi Lukas, Thank you for answering. Can you please elaborate why JOOQ may not be a good solution. From the points, that you mentioned - mockfiledatabase/ mockconnection, can be used to achieve a dummy resultset. What other downsides do you see apart from slowness ?
